# Building HTML similar to Word document styles and binding to data

Tags: html, ms-word

Are there ways to convert Word documents to HTML?
Looking for a way to render something similar looking to Word documents.

Comment: You are probally looking for something like this?

http://word2cleanhtml.com/

Answer (score 0):

refer to this http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=41942#216880 . You can use it straight away